# Praw (Reddit API) How to retrieve replies to a comment past 10 levels deep

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Ok, so I've written some code that, for all intents and purposes, should work:

```
def checkComments(comments):
  for comment in comments:
    print comment.body
    checkComments(comment.replies)

def processSub(sub):
  sub.replace_more_comments(limit=None, threshold=0)
  checkComments(sub.comments)


#login and subreddit init stuff here
subs = mysubreddit.get_hot(limit=25)
for sub in subs:
  processSub(sub)
```

However, given a submission with a comment that has 50 nested replies like so:

```
root comment
-> 1st reply
   -> 2nd reply
      -> 3rd reply
         ...
           -> 50th reply
```

The above code only prints:

```
root comment
1st reply
2nd reply
3rd reply
4th reply
5th reply
6th reply
7th reply
8th reply
9th reply
```

Any idea how I can get the remaining 41 levels of replies?  Or is this a praw limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `limit` limits the number of results, not the result depth.

But that's not the problem here, the `morecomments` endpoint of the reddit API seems to return wrong results for deeply nested comments.

For more technical details, refer to [bug report #321](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/321).